# Angular arrowup with ctrl

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently capturing the arrowup key.

I use this:

```
(keyup.arrowup)="mymethod()"
```

I need to change this to **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>arrowup</kbd>**

How can I do this?

Comment: Try keyup.control.arrowup

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<input (keydown.control.arrowup)="mymethod()">`

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sf4d39